# Get-ChildItem filtered and sorted

Tags: powershell, sorting, filtering, get-childitem

I am trying to select all Uninstall keys in the registry that have a DisplayName property, sorted by Displayname. I would have thought this would work.

```
$uninstall32 = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
$uninstall64 = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
$uninstallKeys = (Get-ChildItem "Registry::$uninstall32" | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName} | sort DisplayName) +
                 (Get-ChildItem "Registry::$uninstall64" | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName} | sort DisplayName)

foreach ($uninstallKey in $uninstallKeys) {
    $uninstallKey
}
```

But that is returning nothing. If I remove the Where-Object I do get results, but not sorted. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't even see `DisplayName` as a property of `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` object. `$uinstallKeys[0] | Get-Member` doesn't show it.

Comment: Yeah, it SEEMS like this should be possible, but it FEELS like Microsoft just never implemented anything like this, and the only real option is to get everything, then conditionally add it to a hash table with DisplayName as the key, then sort the hash table. Which is a ton of work for something that SEEMS like Microsoft should have just provided it.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Check a few more, like `$uninstallKeys[0..9]` or such and you'll probably come across one.

This is one of the quirks with the registry I've never really gotten used to. It has always felt to me as having to catch occasional exceptions from pandas, weather forecasts and the concept of disappointment while you're just coding something for a file system provider - trying to find a file, folder or whatever.

Comment: This is just some strange behavior with `Sort-Object`. `Sort-Object` alone sorts based on the default set of properties for a particular object type ***if*** no properties are provided to the command. But `Sort-Object DisplayName` and `Sort-Object RandomString` both sort the same way, which is different than providing no property at all. This results in three different sorting scenarios: default, by the actual property, or a different view for fake properties. I think an additional `Get-ItemProperty` is required to actually see a `DisplayName` property value.

Comment: `Get-ItemProperty` is the cmdlet to use here to get the DisplayName properties and other... That being said, I had an issue of type "Specified cast is invalid" due to a program registering his key there with something it shouldn't had. To circumvent this, looping through each item then getting the item properties from within a try catch will work perfectly. The only downside is that the key that is in an invalid format will be skipped (if you have any) with the current method.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pipe your `Get-ChildItem` commands into `| Get-ItemProperty` to obtain the desired result.

That being said, I encountered an issue where I had an invalid key in my registry.
To circumvent that possible issue, I iterated into each items and got the property individually.

```
$uninstall32 = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
$uninstall64 = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
$uninstallKeys = (Get-ChildItem "Registry::$uninstall32") +
(Get-ChildItem "Registry::$uninstall64")

$AllKeys = `
  Foreach ($key in $uninstallKeys) {
  try {
    $Value = $Key | Get-ItemProperty -ErrorAction Stop
    $Value
  }
  catch {
    Write-Warning $_
  }
}
$AllKeys  = $AllKeys  | WHere DisplayName -ne '' | sort displayname
```

**Reference**

[Regarding the potential Specified cast is not valid error with Get-ItemProperty & uninstall registry location](https://superuser.com/questions/1352166/how-to-resolve-error-specified-cast-is-not-valid-error-during-installation)

Comment: Yes, this. A lil quirk I noticed with the sorting was that the displayname for ` Tools for .Net 3.5` indeed does begin with a whitespace. Go figure.

Comment: Netbeans makes an invalid dword value in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you either want the key PATHS returned as a string array, OR the keys as Objects, including all properties:

```
$uninstall = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*',
             'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'

$uninstallKeys = $uninstall | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ItemProperty "Registry::$_" | 
    Where-Object {$_.DisplayName} | 
    Sort-Object DisplayName | 
    # if you want the Keys Paths returned as string properties:
    Select-Object @{Name = 'RegistryKey'; Expression = {($_.PSPath -split '::')[1]}}

    # if you want the Keys returned with all properties as objects:
    # Select-Object $_.PSPath
}

$uninstallKeys
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of get-childitem is kind of an illusion.  It actually calls get-itemproperty in the format file.  You need to use get-itemproperty to see values and data.  You may want to use the get-package command instead.  Note that Netbeans makes an invalid registry dword entry "NoModify" when it installs, that creates an exception in get-itemproperty.

Here's an approach with get-itemproperty:

```
get-itemproperty hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall\* | 
  where displayname | sort displayname
```